# overflow-wrap: break-word doesn't effect text

Tags: html, css

I have this css code

```css
.LogLink {
 font-family:courier;
 white-space: pre;
 font-size: 11.6px;
 border: 2px solid rgb(44, 44, 44);  
 background-color:rgb(240, 240, 240);  
 padding:5px;  
 margin-top:5px;  
 margin-bottom:5px;  
 margin-left:20px;  
 margin-right:20px;  
 overflow-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

```html
<h2 style='text-align:center'>LogLink: $BuildID</h2>
<p class='LogLink'>[Env] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
[Env] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
[Env] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
[Env] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................</p>
```

This is how it's displayed on my webpage, and that's good enough: 
[image: It's displayed like this]

the problem is when I have these long lines of text/symbols:
[image]

I thought that `overflow-wrap: break-word;` would help, but it doesn't do anything. Is there a way to make all the text fit page width, without getting a horizontal scrollbar, but a new line? NOTE: I can't edit the text I receive.

The reason why i use `white-space: pre;` is to display my received database text. It's received in one line.

**EDIT**
`white-space: pre;` changed tro `white-space: pre-line;` worked!

```css
.LogLink {
 font-family:courier;
 white-space: pre-line;
 font-size: 11.6px;
 border: 2px solid rgb(44, 44, 44);  
 background-color:rgb(240, 240, 240);  
 padding:5px;  
 margin-top:5px;  
 margin-bottom:5px;  
 margin-left:20px;  
 margin-right:20px;  
 overflow-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

```html
<h2 style='text-align:center'>LogLink: $BuildID</h2>
<p class='LogLink'>[Env] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
[Env] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
[Env] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
[Env] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................</p>
```

Comment: You should provide the output in `text` not `image`. It would help you get quick answers.

Comment: The images from my website? @MasudurRahman

Comment: yes, that's what I suggest.

Comment: the problem was `white-space: pre;`, it should be `white-space: pre-line;`.

Comment: I made a [mcve] for you. Please update the HTML with relevant text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `white-space: pre-wrap;` or `white-space: pre-line;`

Here's a codepen showing an example with `pre-wrap`: https://codepen.io/DavidSabine/pen/Exxvybe

And here's the CSS from my example:

```
.LogLink {
    font-family:courier;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    font-size: 11.6px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(44, 44, 44);  
    background-color:rgb(240, 240, 240);  
    padding:5px;  
    margin-top:5px;  
    margin-bottom:5px;  
    margin-left:20px;  
    margin-right:20px;  
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

The different between pre-wrap and pre-line is described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Whether to use `pre-wrap` or `pre-line` depends whether you want white space sequences preserved or collapsed. This would largely depend on what your raw output looks like (from your database). I recommend try both. Both are well supported in browsers. See the reports at caniuse.com:

https://caniuse.com/#search=pre-line

https://caniuse.com/#search=pre-wrap

Answer (score 0):

try setting a `max-width` on the container containing the `<p>` tag, or even on the `<p>` tag itself. using `width` and `max-width` together will allow it to be responsive;
`width: 400px`
`max-width: 85%`

Comment: the problem was `white-space: pre;`, it should be `white-space: pre-line;`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @MadsSander. I've edited my response to provide an explanation about the pre-line and pre-wrap options. Both are suitable, but the optimal choice will depend largely on how whitespace characters are treated in the raw output.